# How to apply the backgroung colors in AutoCompleteExtender textbox values in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, sql-server-2008

i am binding two table values in AutoCompleteExtender but my requirement is differentiate the two tables apply the colors i.e table1 values apply red color and table2 values apply green color how to write the code pls give me any suggestion 
my code is

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            count = 10;
        }
        DataTable dt = GetRecords(prefixText);
        List<string> items = new List<string>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {          
            string strName = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + ',' + dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();             
            items.Add(strName);
            //items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        }
        return items.ToArray();

    }
```

Getrecords code is

```
public DataTable GetRecords(string strName)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Usp_Consultant1", LITRMSConnection);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consultantname", strName);
                DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        LITRMSConnection.Open();
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
        LITRMSConnection.Close();
        return objDs.Tables[0];
    }
```

and stored procedure is

```
CREATE Procedure Usp_Consultant1
    (@consultantname varchar(100))
As
        Begin
            select  (cast(ConsultantID as varchar)+',Employee')as ConsultantID,(FirstName+LastName)as ConsultantName from Consultant  where FirstName+LastName like +@consultantname+'%'                
            union all           
            select  (cast(ConsID as varchar)+',NonEmployee')as ConsultantID,(Firstname+LastName)as consultantName from InDirectConsultant  where FirstName+LastName like +@consultantname+'%'   
            ORDER BY 1;
        End
```

pls give me any suggestion....

thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer is add the javascript function

```
 function getCustomers_Populated(sender, e) {

        var customers = sender.get_completionList().childNodes;
        var searchText = sender.get_element().value;

        for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {

            var customer = customers[i];
            var customerValueArray = (customer._value).split(",");
            var customerId = customerValueArray[0];
            var type = customerValueArray[2];
             customers[i].innerHTML = customerId;
            if (type == 'Employee') {
                customers[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
            else {
                customers[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            }


        }
```

Comment: Good answer.  No need to start with the word "answer".  Also, add more information such as code comments and text introduction would be better.

Answer (score 0):

To selectively apply background colors to the autocompleteextender items you will probably have to use JavaScript.

Since all the items from one table contain the string `',Employee'` and the items from the other contain `',NonEmployee'` you can use that information for styling.

Set the properties:

```
OnClientShown="autoCompleteShow"
CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem"
```

on the `AutoCompleteExtender`.

Inside `autoCompleteShow` we style the `<li>` items background color according to the table from which they came:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function autoCompleteShow() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
      if (elements[i].innerHTML.search(",Employee") != -1)
        elements[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#4CC417", "!important");
      else
        elements[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "Red", "!important");
  }
</script>
```

Working demo code:

[WebForm1.aspx]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoCompleteExtenderContextualItemBgColor.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem 
    {
        color : White;
    }
    .AutoCompleteExtender_HighlightedItem
    {
        color : Black;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function autoCompleteShow() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
          if (elements[i].innerHTML.search(",Employee") != -1)
            elements[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#4CC417", "!important");
          else
            elements[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "Red", "!important");
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" Width="250" />
      <asp:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server"
        ID="myAutoCompleteExtender"
        TargetControlID="myTextBox"
        ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" 
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
        CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem"
        CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_HighlightedItem"
        OnClientShown="autoCompleteShow">
      </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[AutoComplete.asmx(markup)]

```
<%@ WebService
    Language="C#"
    CodeBehind="~/App_Code/AutoComplete.cs"
    Class="AutoComplete" %>
```

[~/App_Code/AutoComplete.cs]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : WebService
{
    public AutoComplete()
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            count = 10;
        }

        List<string> items =
            new List<string>() { "test1 ,Employee Hgeurg Jfheuf",
                                 "test2 ,NonEmployee Uheure Iueir",
                                 "test3 ,Employee Jufhwiufhiwe Leroe",
                                 "test5 ,Employee Cgrejg Jehure Byer",
                                 "test7 ,NonEmployee Qewrerffx Yegr" };
        return items.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem');  This line javascript error is occured, i think there is no object passing in element variable pls tel me which object i can access that place

Comment: It is not wroking error in var elements line pls give me some guidlines

Comment: have you set `CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoCompleteExtender_CompletionListItem"` on the `AutoCompleteExtender`?